# Cannot override mutable property 'collectionView' of type 'UICollectionView?' with covariant type 'GeminiCollectionView?'

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, gemini

I have had a custom collection view and everything worked fine. I wanted to include 'Gemini' to make beautiful animations when sliding my cells horizontally. I believe that the problem is not Gemini, I think the same would have happen with changing VC class to any other one, but I dont know how to solve this because I never faced with this before, is there a shortcut from this?

I have installed and imported the pod into code.

I had a UICollectionViewController but to work with gemini I needed to connect my collectionView from Storyboard to ViewController. Before that, I have put a class in Storyboard for my CollectionView to be GeminiCollectionView like in the image below:

[image: Storyboard coll.view class]

After that, I changed a class for my CollectionView in ViewController, too, like in the image below and got those three errors: 
[image]

In the later code, it doesnt show any errors:

`viewDidLoad`

```
collectionView.gemini
            .rollRotationAnimation()
            .degree(45)
            .rollEffect(.rollUp)
```

`cellForItemAt`

```
self.collectionView.animateCell(cell)
```

`scrollViewDidScroll`

```
self.collectionView.animateVisibleCells()
```

`willDisplay cell`

```
if let cell = cell as? RatingCell {
//RatingCell inhertis the GeminiCell class
            self.collectionView.animateCell(cell)
        }
```

So, all the code is fine except the declaration as I mentioned at the beginning and here:

```
@IBOutlet var collectionView: GeminiCollectionView!
```

*Waiting for random guys to unvote this :P*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

```
@IBOutlet var collectionView: GeminiCollectionView!
```

That line was a problem. Seems like you mustn't default Swift's name to override mutable property, which is `collectionView` for Collection Views and `tableView` for Table Views.

I changed that line to

```
@IBOutlet var collView: GeminiCollectionView!
```

...and the errors disappeared.